# How do I check for every element in a nested list to eventually receive one list that has a value of more than 67 in the dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a nested list:

```
groups = [['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno'], ['mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx']]
```

The dictionary:

```
respective_numbers = {'abc': 33,'def': 33,'ghi': 32, 'jkl': 11, 'mno': 9,'pqr': 8, 'stu': 6,'vwx': 3}
```

I start the function with

```
def enough_numbers(groups, respective_numbers):
```

I want a function which checks all lists out of the nested list and if these lists have a (corresponding) value from the dictionary above 67 that that list gets printed. In this case the list that gets printed is

```
['mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx']
```

Comment: What does "have a (corresponding) value from the dictionary above 67" mean?  Nothing has a value above 33 in your dictionary.

Comment: I would start here and then iterate the flattened list against your dictionary keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-arbitrarily-nested-list-of-lists